# Tour page: mention that questions seeking off-site resources are off-topic

Tags: discussion, status-completed, allowed-topics

The [tour page](https://money.stackexchange.com/tour) currently says:

> Ask about...
>
> - Personal investing and asset allocation
> - The financial aspects of homebuying
> - Best practices for saving for retirement, education, and other goals
> - Strategies for creating and sticking to a budget
> - Strategies for earning and saving more money
>
> Don't ask about...
>
> - Anything not directly related to Personal Finance and Money
> - Questions that are primarily opinion-based
> - Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer

Something important is missing:

> Questions seeking product, service recommendations or other off-site resources are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Should it be added to the tour page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I appear to have the power to edit this unilaterally and have just done so:

> - Anything not directly related to Personal Finance and Money
> - Questions that are primarily opinion-based
> - Questions with too many possible
>   answers or that would require an extremely long answer
> - Product or
>   service recommendations or comparisons

I copied the text from [StackOverflow's tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

(I say unilaterally because some other things mods can do to the site setup require the approval of another mod too.)

I did it quickly because it seemed fairly obvious to me, but if anyone disagrees, leave another answer and we can always undo this.